# Computing k means in python and plotting over the scatter plot

Tags: python, k-means

Am running a cluster analysis in python using K-means and the code below get me stuck please help.

```py
X = df[['List Agency Code', 'Exam No']].copy()   


kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=4, init='k-means++', max_iter=300, n_init=10, random_state=0)
pred_y = kmeans.fit_predict(X)
plt.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1]) #This never works, and its what i need.

plt.scatter(kmeans.cluster_centers_[:, 0], kmeans.cluster_centers_[:, 1], s=300, c='red')
plt.show()
```

NOTE: If i replace `plt.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1])` with
`plt.scatter(df['List Agency Code'], df['Exam No'])` it works

Comment: Did you tried `plt.scatter(X['List Agency Code'], X['Exam No'])`?

Comment: Please, format your question appropriately: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting. It's easier to read if the code is written in code blocks.

Comment: Also, explain what do you mean by "This never works". Do you get an error? A result different than the one you expect?

Comment: Thanks – Ignatius Reilly.  plt.scatter(X['List Agency Code'], X['Exam No']) this works